# Spring Webclient, The connection observed an error io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

To make a call to an external payment gateway from the spring boot application, we are making use of webclient that comes along with webflux.

Stack:

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.3

spring-boot-starter-webflux 2.5.6

This API calls although at times, with negligible load (on our test environments) fail with the error `The connection observed an error io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already`

Here's the trace

```
[id:31e016c9-2, L:/x.xx.xxx.xx:56499 - R:xxx.payu.in/xy.xyy.xyyy.xyy:443] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:861)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:800)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:781)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.flush(LoggingHandler.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:531)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:765)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:306)
    at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$send$0(HttpOperations.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4338)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:424)
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:654)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.run(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:287)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The web client bean that is used is as shown below

```
@Bean
    public WebClient apiClient() {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build();
    }
```

Dependency tree

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.9:compile
```

I know there are a lot of threads around this lately, but none of them have a solution.

Related threads:
[javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already SSLEngine closed already in webclient (Springboot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599212/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-sslengine-closed-already-sslengine-closed-already-in)
[Spring WebClient: SSLEngine closed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463346/spring-webclient-sslengine-closed-already)
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/782

Answer (score 1):

I updated the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 2.5.6 to 2.5.14, because 2.5.14 is a patch that uses reactor-netty-http version 1.0.19. [1.0.18 has an important fix](https://%20https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/releases/tag/v1.0.18) related to how connections are handled.

`Do not return the connection to the pool in case SSLEngine has been closed`

This alone although didn't solve the issue.
Setting maxIdleTime did the trick. Here's what I did.

```
@Bean
    public WebClient apiClient() {

        /*
         * Setting maxIdleTime as 10s, because servers usually have a keepAliveTimeout
         * of 60s, after which the connection gets closed.
         * If the connection pool has any connection which has been idle for over 10s, it
         * will be evicted from the pool.
         * Refer https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1318#issuecomment-702668918
         */
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.builder("connectionProvider")
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider)
            .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build();
    }
```